# Python: ax.text not displaying in saved PDF

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a figure with some text (example here: a sin curve with some text on the side) in an ipython notebook. The plot and text show up inline in my notebook, but when I save the figure I only see the plot and not the text. I've reproduced the problem with this example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.text(8,0.9,'Some Text Here',multialignment='left', linespacing=2.)
plt.savefig('sin.pdf')
```

How can I see the text in the saved pdf?

Comment: The text coordinates (8,0.9) are not within the displayed range of the graph I would guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figures shown in jupyter notebook are saved png images. They are saved with the option `bbox_inches="tight"`.

In order to produce a pdf which looks exactly the same as the png in the notebook, you also need to use this option.

```
plt.savefig('sin.pdf', bbox_inches="tight")
```

The reason is that the coordinates (8,0.9) are outside the figure. So the text won't appear in the saved version of it (It wouldn't appear in an interactive figure either). The option `bbox_inches="tight"` expands or shrinks the saved range to include all elements of the canvas. Using this option is indeed useful for easily including elements which are outside the plot without having to care about figure size, margins and coordinates at all.

A final note: You are specifying the text's position in data coordinates. This is usually undesired, because it makes the text's position dependent on what data is shown in the axes. Instead it would make sense to specify it in axes coordiantes,

```
ax.text(1.1, .9, 'Some Text Here', va="top", transform=ax.transAxes)
```

such that it always sits at position `(1.1,.9)` with respect to the axes.

Answer (score -1):

The code is a full working example based on OPs' question. Based on previous comments by other user the answer is updated and modified. Inline comments address where issue is solved.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

# add filename at start prevents confusion lateron.
with PdfPages('Sin.pdf') as pdf:    

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)
    ax.plot(x, y)

    # ax.text : 8 > 0.8 and 0.9 => 0.5 keeps text under parabola inside the grid. 
    ax.text(0.8, 0.5, 'Some Text Here', linespacing=2, fontsize=12, multialignment='left')   

    # example of axis labels.
    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)', title='Sin-wave') 

    ax.grid()

    # you can add a pdf note to attach metadata to a page
    pdf.attach_note("plot of sin(x)", positionRect=[-100, -100, 0, 0])

    # saves the current figure into a pdf page    
    plt.savefig(pdf, format = 'pdf')
    plt.close()
```